# Android : Compress & Insert images into SQLite Database

Tags: android, image, sqlite, compression, blob

I'm working on an app, in witch i need to store more than 1600 images (.PNG) in BLOB format. Each image has nearly 230KB in size.

What i want to do, is to compress images to someting below 20KB. So as a result the whole size of images will be around 32 MB (1600 x 20KB) and the final apk size will be reduced.

To explain more : what i want to do is to compress images from 230KB to under 20KB to save more space in the database. the database will be filled with data and images before integrating it in the apk.

So if i compressed images stored in database. the database size will reduce. and it will not take a lot of space inside APK

Any suggestions on how to do that ?

NOTE : the Database will be filled with information before integrating in the app.

Comment: What is your problem doing so?

Comment: What has putting images in a database to do with the size of your apk or even your apk? Where is the connection? How do you integrate it?

Comment: i did an update. on what exactly i want.

Comment: I still do not understand where that database would be inside your apk. I still do not understand which problems you have with the things you want.

Comment: @greenapps the database usually exist in Assets folder inside apk. if you have ever integrated a pre-filled database to an APK you will know what i'm talking about.

Comment: Ok. Now that we know that you put the database file in the assets folder its really time that you explain which troubles you have to realize the things you want. Third time i ask.

Comment: the trouble i have is i want to compress the images that i'm going to store in that database as much as possible and i dont know how. If you can suggest how to do that i would be thankful.

Comment: It is also a good idea to tell us how your app would use the images in the database file in the assets folder.

Comment: the database will be in assets folder. and inside that database i will store images in a table in BLOB format. and when i need to fetch an image from it. i will do it with regular queries and get it as a bytes array.

Comment: It is unclear which problem you exactly have. And what you mean with 'compress'. You want smaller image file sizes we understand. You can do that in several ways which all have pros and contras. Tell us your considerations and problems. And dont de forget to answer my former comment.

Comment: You cannot query a database file which is in assets unless you build a content provider.

Comment: my problem is not how to get the image from the database. my problem is how to compress them so they will not take a lot of space.

Comment: Yes we already know that long time now. You only repeat yourself. Not needed. Better explain why you are unable to compress an image in one of the many ways.

Comment: that's exactly what i'm looking for. those many ways that can help me to compress those images.

Comment: Well name and tell your problems with them. Moreover you did still not tell where you want to do that. Who should do it? Or do you want to write a pc program for it? Windows. Linux. Mac? Its astounding that you give so little info.

Comment: any way thank you for trying to help i will look further for solutions

Comment: @SaidTagnit I cannot understand why your problem was so difficult to solve by greenapps. I understand that you just wanted the best piece of code in which you could save as much storage space as you could. So if you've solved your problem, please let the community know!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be the best to store those images on server, and once user downloads your app you should transfer images to app.
1600 is really a big number for app before it's installed...

Answer (score -1):

I do not know if this is the best way to save storage space using SQLite and I am still looking for it, but here we go.

You can select the source of your image, such as gallery or camera and below is the code.

```
private void selectProductImage() {
        final CharSequence[] itens = {"Use Camera", "Gallery", "Cancel"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.AlertDialog);
        builder.setItems(itens, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (itens[which].equals("Use Camera")) {
                    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Use Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
                    } else {
                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    }

                } else if (itens[which].equals("Gallery")) {
                    Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_GALLERY_PHOTO);

                } else if (itens[which].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

Maybe you need permission to use the camera

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

    }
```

Here is how to handle the image from the source you selected.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"),96, 96, true);
        mProductImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        isPriviteImage = true;
    }

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        //mProductImage.setImageURI(data.getData());

        // INSERT IMAGE INTO SQLite
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream),96, 96, true);
            mProductImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            isPriviteImage = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

As you can notice in my example, there is no place to save the image case you selected **camera** and I placed the image on an `ImageView` variable named **mProductImage**.

From now, you can use a **Button** to save the image in your SQLite Database. Here is the function you can use for it.

```
private void saveImage() {

    productTablePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/YourAditionalPath/";

    ProductDatabaseHelper productDatabaseHelper = new ProductDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext(), "dbname.db", productTablePath);
    productListTable = productDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    productRepository = new ProductRepository(productListTable);

    try {

        if (isPriviteImage) {
            productRepository.addProduct(imageViewToByte(mProductImage));
            isPriviteImage = false;

        } else {
            productRepository.addProduct(null);

        }

        mProductImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.shopping_cart_black_48dp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Where `imageViewToByte` functon is:

```
private byte[] imageViewToByte(CircleImageView image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
```

Now you need to implement the **SQLiteOpenHelper**. You need to create a new class for this. The java file name I used for this was **ProductDatabaseHelper.java**.

```
public class ProductDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static int dbVersion = 1;

    public ProductDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, String storageDirectory) {
        super(context, storageDirectory+name, null, dbVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

        sql.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRODUCTLIST (");

        sql.append("        IMAGE        BLOB,");


        db.execSQL(sql.toString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Now you need to implement your CRUD (Create new item, Read, Update and Delete).

```
public class ProductRepository {

    SQLiteDatabase instance;

    public ProductRepository(SQLiteDatabase instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void addProduct(byte[] image){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("IMAGE",image);

        instance.insertOrThrow("PRODUCTLIST",null, contentValues);
    }


}
```

It is important to mention that the compression of the image was made in the `onActivityResult()` for both source image (camera and gallery).

with the command:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(capturedImage, width, height, true);
```

Besides that, here is a link where we can read a little bit about compression.

https://androidwave.com/capture-image-from-camera-gallery/

If you have a better way to compress images to save in SQLite Database, please post your code here!